# How can I get a reference of a script from a second object that is contained in a List that belongs to the this script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a MonoBehaviour `Container` that has a list of a default class `Box` (which is serializable so that I can modify its fields in `Container` inspector) and an `Animator`.

In editor time, I'm editing the `Box`es in the list of my `Container`. How can I access the `Container` that contains the `Box` I'm editing (inside the `Box` code)?

Basically I want to have a function inside `Box` that returns all animations from the animator stored in the `Container`.

I don't want to create a field in `Box` to store the reference for its `Container` but I don't mind using reflection or whatever it takes to access this Animator from the `Container`.

This is only needed when I'm editing the inspector of `Container` so it will be the current thing shown in the inspector, in case that helps.

Comment: You would need to add some kinda parent field to box, and have the container fill it in when its added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GameObject gameObject = (GameObject)Selection.activeObject` did the job.

It returns the currently selected GameObject, which will be the correct one in the moment I'm making modifications to its `Box` list in the inspector.

Comment: While this might be enough for your specific use case - for the future reader [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138206/how-can-i-get-a-reference-of-a-script-from-a-second-object-that-is-contained-in/78140327#comment137767313_78140327) have in mind that there are edge cases not covered by this

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you would need to / should inject this from the `Container` down to the referenced `Box`es.

As a very quick-and-dirty solution something like e.g.

```
public class Box : MonoBehaviour
{
    // serialize but (optional) don't show in Inspector
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector] private Container _container;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public void SetContainer(Container container)
    {
        if(_container == container) return;

        _container = container;
        UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
    }
#endif

    ...
}
```

and then

```
public class Container : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerilaizeField] private List<Box> _boxes;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // called whenever you change something via the Inspector of this component
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        foreach(var box in _boxes)
        {
            if(!box) continue;

            box.SetContainer(this);
        }
    }
#endif

    ...
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve it using `GameObject gameObject = (GameObject)Selection.activeObject`, it gets me the current gameobject selected in the hierarchy!

Comment: @Daniel not necessarily in all cases e.g. if another object is selected but you locked the Inspector for this Container .. which is actually a common practice when you want to select multiple `Box` objects and add them all at once to the list by drag & drop ... the above would still work in that case ;)